# May I change the behavior of the close button on MAC with Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm developing a software on Mac on which a login screen appears straight after the software has been opened.

This is a typical login screen, but, I'd like that when the users closes this pop-up, not only the login screen closes, but also the software himself.

Is that possible ?

Comment: May be you can change a header on the window and add custom close button.

Comment: I thought of that, but since this is the very first time I'm manipulating xib files, I got to figure out how I can do that..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard to manage your view hierarchies, then, in your login view controller, you can use the following logic for closing the app:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear {
    [super viewDidDisappear];
    if (shouldTerminalApp) { // you should have this iv to decide if user has entered the login credential for login or if the user closed the login view without entering anything.
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
    } else {
        // perform login procedures
    }
}
```

You can also observe NSWindowWillCloseNotification and in the notification handler, simply call [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil] in the correct case.